# Adding events to android calendar failing

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentresolver, android-cursor

I am trying to add events to a user's calendar programatically. I have followed countless guides here on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but none of them will make that damned event show up in my calendar. Here is my current code:

```
public void saveGamesToCalendar() {
    showCalendarPopup();
}

private void showCalendarPopup() {
    final ContentResolver cr;
    final Cursor result;
    final Uri uri;
    List<String> listCals = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String[] projection = new String[] {CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME,};

    uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

    cr = context.getContentResolver();
    result = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(result.getCount() > 0 && result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                listCals.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME)));
    } while(result.moveToNext());
}
CharSequence[] calendars = listCals.toArray(new CharSequence[listCals.size()]);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Calendar to use:");
builder.setItems(calendars, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int itemCal) {
            Log.e("SettingsActivity", "CalendarID: " + itemCal);
            loopThroughGames(itemCal);
        };
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private void loopThroughGames(int whichCalendar) {
    ArrayList<Model_Game> games = memoryManager.getGames();

    // for(Game e: games)
    Log.e("Game", games.get(101).toString());
    addGameToCalendar(games.get(101), whichCalendar);

    Log.e("ID", "" + whichCalendar);
}

private void addGameToCalendar(Model_Game game,int whichCalendar) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    try {
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, whichCalendar);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Hockey- " + game.getLeague() + ": " + game.getTeamH() + " vs " + game.getTeamA());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Twin Rinks Ice Arena- " + game.getRink() + " Rink");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, "" + game.getCalendarObject().getTimeInMillis());
        //values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, "" + game.getCalendarObject().getTimeInMillis() + 5400000);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "" + 5400000);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

        cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        toast(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Basically what is going on is that the user presses an action bar button, which calls the `saveGamesToCalendar()` method, which calls the `ShowCalendarPopup()` method. This method shows a standard dialog with the list of the user's calendars, and when the user selects one of them, the `loopThroughGames()` method is called with the ID of the chosen calendar as a parameter. This method will, when everything is working, write all the user's games to the calendar, but for testing purposes it only writes one. The `addGameToCalendar()` method takes a game object, which holds lots of values like time, title, location, date, etc., and inserts it into the calendar using the standard way outlined in many different places on the web.

I am getting no error messages with this code (other than the ones I send to the error log myself) so I have no idea why this code isn't working. No errors, just the games never show up in my calendar. I have the permissions set correctly in the manifest so I know that isn't the problem.

Does anyone have a solution to this annoying problem? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

[RE-EDIT]]
This is what I did and it works like a charm..

```
         Cursor cursor = null ;

         String[] projection = new String[] {
                   CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                   CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,};

         ContentResolver cr = context2.getContentResolver();
         cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), projection, null, null, null);

         if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
                final String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
                calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
                    calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                    calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        try {           

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

//          int apiLevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
//            if(apiLevel<14){
//              values.put("visibility", 0);
//
//            }
            values.put(Events.DTSTART, stTime);
            values.put(Events.DTEND, enTime);
            values.put(Events.TITLE, category);
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calIds[0]);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION,place);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,tZone);

            mInsert =  cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            Toast.makeText(context2, "Event added Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context2, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: What API level did you test this on. I ran this code on API 17 (android 4.2) and it did not work. calNames was full of null's and calIds was full of 0's. I think this way doesn't work on newer versions of Android, after API 14.

Comment: Ohh sorry about that, I have revised the code and it should work properly now :)

Answer (score 0):

protected void eventAdding() {

```
    try
    {
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2013, 11, 20, 8,0 );
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2013, 11, 20, 8, 50);
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();




      ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
      values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
      values.put(Events.TITLE, "Hello");

      values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);            
      values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());


if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {

         uri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
     } else 
     {

         uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
     }
      Uri urievent = cr.insert(uri, values);    


     } 
catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

       }

    //event = Utility.readCalendarEvent(CalnderEvent.this);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This works and is much easier to understand:

```
     long startTime = calSet.getTimeInMillis();
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                 .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, startTime + (length*3600000))
                .putExtra(Events.TITLE, examName)
                .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, venue)
                .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
                .putExtra(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

                 startActivity(intent);
```